# jQuery fade in/out while applying CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to apply css styles on fade in/out. My bad that JS is not my forte. Any idea how to put those two functions together?

```
    $(".share").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".social-overlay-outer").fadeIn({.css("display", "block")});
    });
    $(".share").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".social-overlay-outer").fadeOut({.css("display", "none")});
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question; adding css styles in jQuery is done by adding the function to the end of the previous one *(see example below)*.

**NOTE:** [fadeOut](https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) functionality transitions css `opacity` and adds `display:none` to the element when the animation completes and is not necessary as in your example.

```js
$(".share").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".social-overlay-outer").fadeIn().css("color", "red");
});
$(".share").mouseleave(function() {
  $(".social-overlay-outer").fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="share">SHARE</div>
<div class="social-overlay-outer">Social</div>
```

---

If you want to add css styles to the element once the fadeIn animation completes you can instead use the callback parameter of the function.

> .fadeIn( [duration ] [, complete ] )

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn1").click(function() {
    $("p").fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $(this).css("font-size","10px");
    });
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function() {
    $("p").fadeIn("5s", function() {
      $(this).css("font-size","20px");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
<button class="btn2">Fade in</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @DreamTek, I see where I was wrong. It worked perfectly.